# Can I delete libc-bin?

Tags: uninstall, delete

Question is simple, I need to know because I cant upgrade/install anything, because it always says I have to uninstall/delete it to continue. It also says dont do it, if I dont know what I am doing.

EDIT: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqtgui4:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-network:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-opengl:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-qt3support:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-script:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-scripttools:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-sql:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-svg:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-test:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libcups2:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libcupsimage2:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libcurl3:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnss3:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnspr4:i386 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not installed
                            Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not installed
                            Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not installed
 lib32ffi6 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 lib32gcc1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.5) but it is not installed
 lib32nss-mdns : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libacl1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libattr1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libaudio2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libavahi-client3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installed
 libavahi-common3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libcomerr2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.12) but it is not installed
 libdb5.1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.4) but it is not installed
 libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.4) but it is not installed
 libdrm2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libffi6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libfontconfig1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                       Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 1.95.8) but it is not installed
                       Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not installed
 libgcrypt11:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libgdbm3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.9) but it is not installed
 libgpg-error0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libice6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libidn11:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libjpeg62:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libkeyutils1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 liblcms1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libllvm2.9:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libmng1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libpciaccess0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libpcre3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 librtmp0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                 Depends: libgnutls26:i386 (>= 2.9.11-0) but it is not installed
 libsasl2-2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libsasl2-modules:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
 libselinux1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not installed
 libsm6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libsqlite3-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libuuid1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libx11-6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxau6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxdamage1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libxdmcp6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxext6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxfixes3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libxrender1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libxss1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libxt6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libxxf86vm1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

szikszay@szikszay-Latitude-E5530-non-vPro:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Correcting dependencies... Done

The following packages will be REMOVED

  libc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libc-bin:i386 libc6:i386 libc6-i386 libcups2:i386 libcupsimage2:i386
  libcurl3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfreetype6:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libgnutls26:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386
  libpng12-0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386
  libqt4-designer:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386
  libqt4-qt3support:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386
  libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-xml:i386
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
  libtasn1-3:i386 libtiff4:i386 libxi6:i386
The following packages have been kept back:
  ginn libgrip0 linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic unity unity-common
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice acpi-support acpid aisleriot alsa-utils
  app-install-data-partner apparmor appmenu-qt apport apport-gtk apt
  apt-transport-https apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data apturl apturl-common
  at-spi2-core bamfdaemon banshee banshee-extension-soundmenu
  banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore baobab bind9-host binutils bluez
  bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common
  brltty bzip2 ca-certificates-java checkbox checkbox-gtk colord
  command-not-found command-not-found-data compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome
  compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-main-default cups cups-bsd cups-client
  cups-common cups-ppdc dbus dbus-x11 deja-dup desktop-file-utils dnsutils
  dpkg ecryptfs-utils empathy empathy-common eog evince evince-common
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common file-roller firefox
  firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support firefox-locale-en firefox-locale-hu
  gbrainy gcalctool gconf2 gconf2-common gedit gedit-common ghostscript
  ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-gconf-2.0
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-unity-4.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0
  gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop3-data gnome-font-viewer
  gnome-games-common gnome-icon-theme gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screenshot
  gnome-search-tool gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra
  gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-utils-common gnomine gnupg gpgv grub-common
  grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gstreamer0.10-gconf
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gvfs gvfs-backends
  gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook
  gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter gzip hpijs hplip hplip-cups
  hplip-data icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx ifupdown
  im-switch indicator-datetime indicator-session indicator-sound
  initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts insserv isc-dhcp-client
  isc-dhcp-common iso-codes jockey-common jockey-gtk language-pack-en
  language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base
  language-pack-gnome-hu language-pack-gnome-hu-base language-pack-hu
  language-pack-hu-base language-selector-common language-selector-gnome
  libaccountsservice0 libapt-inst1.3 libapt-pkg4.11 libarchive1
  libasound2-plugins libatk-adaptor libatspi2.0-0 libbamf0 libbamf3-0
  libbind9-60 libbluetooth3 libbrasero-media3-1 libbrlapi0.5 libbz2-1.0
  libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcamel-1.2-29 libcanberra-gtk-module
  libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module
  libcanberra-pulse libcanberra0 libcolord1 libcups2 libcupscgi1
  libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3-gnutls
  libdbus-1-3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdecoration0 libdns69 libebackend-1.2-1
  libebook1.2-12 libecal1.2-10 libecryptfs0 libedata-book-1.2-11
  libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserver1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1 libevince3-3
  libexif12 libexpat1 libfreetype6 libgail-3-0 libgail-3-common libgck-1-0
  libgconf2-4 libgcr-3-1 libgdata-common libgdata13 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa libgnome-bluetooth8
  libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2 libgnutls26 libgoa-1.0-0
  libgs9 libgs9-common libgssapi-krb5-2 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common
  libgudev-1.0-0 libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2
  libgwibber2 libhpmud0 libicu44 libimobiledevice2 libisc62 libisccc60
  libisccfg62 libjasper1 libjs-jquery libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  libldap-2.4-2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblwres60 libmetacity-private0
  libmission-control-plugins0 libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil
  libmono-csharp4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil
  libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil
  libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil
  libmysqlclient16 libnautilus-extension1 libncurses5 libncursesw5
  libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2
  libnotify0.4-cil libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-1d libnux-1.0-0 libnux-1.0-common
  libpam-gnome-keyring libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime
  libpam0g libperl5.12 libpng12-0 libpoppler-glib6 libpoppler13 libproxy0
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libpython2.7
  libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script
  libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns
  libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-gb
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-hu libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-l10n-common libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za
  libreoffice-l10n-hu libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-human
  libreoffice-writer libsane-hpaio libsmbclient libsnmp-base libsnmp15
  libssl1.0.0 libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libt1-5 libtasn1-3 libtiff4 libtinfo5
  libtotem0 libubuntuone-1.0-1 libubuntuone1.0-cil libudev0
  libunity-core-4.0-4 libunity6 libusbmuxd1 libv4l-0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2
  libvorbisfile3 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libxi6 libxml2 libxslt1.1 lightdm
  linux-firmware linux-libc-dev mawk metacity metacity-common
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mono-4.0-gac mono-gac
  mono-runtime mousetweaks multiarch-support mysql-common nautilus
  nautilus-data nautilus-sendto-empathy ncurses-base ncurses-bin
  network-manager network-manager-gnome nux-tools onboard openjdk-6-jre
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openssl perl perl-base perl-modules
  poppler-utils pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils python-apport python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon-gtk
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets python-brlapi
  python-crypto python-cups python-cupshelpers python-egenix-mxdatetime
  python-egenix-mxtools python-gobject python-gobject-cairo python-httplib2
  python-keyring python-launchpadlib python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-pam
  python-papyon python-pkg-resources python-problem-report python-pyatspi2
  python-software-properties python-ubuntuone-client
  python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno python2.7 python2.7-minimal
  qdbus samba-common samba-common-bin seahorse shotwell simple-scan smbclient
  sni-qt software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  sudo system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
  system-config-printer-udev sysv-rc sysvinit-utils telepathy-indicator
  telepathy-mission-control-5 thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb
  thunderbird-locale-en-us thunderbird-locale-hu tomboy totem totem-common
  totem-mozilla totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk
  ttf-opensymbol tzdata tzdata-java ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-standard ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome
  ubuntuone-couch udev unity-lens-applications unity-services uno-libs3
  update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common
  upstart ure usbmuxd vim-common vim-tiny vinagre vino whois x11-common
  xdiagnose xorg xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl xul-ext-ubufox

WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.

This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!

  libc-bin

498 upgraded, 40 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

69 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 439 MB of archives.
After this operation, 135 MB of additional disk space will be used.
You are about to do something potentially harmful
To continue type in the phrase ‘Yes, do as I say!’
 ?]
```

I tried to upgrade but it gives me an error, when i try to upgrade-f it says i should delete libc-bin. Thanks for the answers btw.

EDIT2: it also says this:

```
The package system is broken
If you are using third party repositories then disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Now run the following command in a terminal: apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Pleae provide details on the commands used and the messages shows. And no, you do not delete it.

Comment: I agree with Rinzwind DO NOT DELETE libc-bin. Please run sudo apt-get update && upgrade  and post the EXACT error

Comment: Edited it, here is some info

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Don't try to delete it, without it you can not start the bash shell.

Comment: Try to fix your  `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does apt output "WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed." and prompt me to enter the full phrase when purging a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436171/why-does-apt-output-warning-the-following-essential-packages-will-be-removed)

Answer (score 0):

No. Just don't do it. My `dpkg` would still be running if I hadn't idiotically done so.

EDIT: What happened was my dpkg became broken, and had unmet dependencies I could not get back because dpkg was broken. I had to do a clean reinstall.

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing this to expand it with a specific explanation of what went wrong after you removed the package.