# add 14.04 ppa in 12.04 source.list and install package messed up the WHOLE system

Tags: package-management, source-packages

I was adding trusty(14.04) ppa to my 12.04 in order to install python3-progressbar. after successfully installed the python3-progressbar. I use `apt-get install synaptic` to install synaptic package. (with the trusty ppa in my source.list. It installed lost of 14.04 packages and removed lots of 12.04 packages.

A error happened before finish the installation of synaptic package. every time I use the command `apt-get install synaptic` will give me the following error messages:

```
$sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
synaptic is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptdaemon : Depends: python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1-1ubuntu5) but it is not installable
         Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: lintian but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-power-manager : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (>= 3.2) but it is not installable
 gnome-screensaver : Depends: libsystemd-login0 (>= 31) but it is not installable
 indicator-power : Depends: liburl-dispatcher1 (>= 0.1) but it is not installable
               Recommends: unity-control-center but it is not installable or
                           gnome-control-center (>= 3.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                           ubuntu-system-settings but it is not installable or
                           xfce4-power-manager but it is not going to be installed
 indicator-session : Depends: systemd-services but it is not installable
                 Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas but it is not installable
                 Recommends: unity-control-center but it is not installable or
                             gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: unity-control-center-signon but it is not installable or
                             gnome-control-center-signon but it is not installable
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.19) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 is to be installed
 libgail-3-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.32.4) but it is not installable
 libglib2.0-0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libelfg0 (>= 0.8.12) but it is not going to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libpcre3-dev (>= 1:8.31) but 8.12-4 is to be installed
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.32.4) but it is not installable
 libp11-kit0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 is to be installed
 libpango1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but it is not installable
             Depends: libpangoxft-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but it is not installable
             Depends: libpangox-1.0-0 (>= 0.0.2-2~) but it is not installable
 libpangocairo-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.32.4) but it is not installable
 libpangoft2-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.36.0) but it is not installable
 libudev1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 is to be installed
 libxkbcommon0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 is to be installed
 nautilus : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.20.0) but it is not installable
 python-apt : Depends: libapt-inst1.5 (>= 0.8.11) but it is not installable
          Depends: libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.9.11) but 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.22 is to be installed
 python-gi : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.33.10) but 1.32.0-1 is to be installed
         Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 (>= 1.35.9) but 1.32.0-1 is to be installed
 unity-greeter : Depends: libido3-0.1-0 (>= 13.10.0daily13.06.19) but 0.3.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: liblightdm-gobject-1-0 (>= 1.4.0) but 1.2.3-0ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
             Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
             Recommends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not installable
             Recommends: indicator-datetime but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: indicator-keyboard but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I then remove the line `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe` in the etc/apt/source.list. After doing this, I run the command `sudo apt-get -f install` command as suggested. It give the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopencc1 python-libproxy libical0 python-keyring dnsmasq-base espeak libnet-ssleay-perl iputils-tracepath folks-common libmtp9 libyaml-tiny-perl libnl-3-200 libpth20 laptop-detect
  libbrlapi0.5 python-twisted-bin python-sphinx python-mako python-pastedeploy python-configglue libnux-2.0-common libwmf0.2-7 intel-gpu-tools libraw5 libprotobuf7 libdiscid0 libmtp-runtime
  liburi-perl dnsutils fonts-opensymbol libhtml-parser-perl sphinx-doc libhyphen0 python-piston-mini-client python-louis liblouis-data libglew1.6 libhttp-daemon-perl syslinux-legacy
  libexttextcat0 libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl ubuntu-extras-keyring git-man libpython3.4 gnome-menus empathy-common python-speechd python-egenix-mxtools docutils-common
  python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol mobile-broadband-provider-info python-launchpadlib libx86-1 libfont-afm-perl python-zope.interface libhttp-negotiate-perl guile-1.8-libs python-oauth
  libfile-listing-perl libhtml-form-perl libwps-0.2-2 syslinux-common libdotconf1.0 python-lxml gnome-control-center-data python-twisted-web python-pyinotify libsigc++-2.0-0c2a
  libfile-desktopentry-perl libexttextcat-data libthai-data python-serial toshset transmission-common python-debtagshw libpcrecpp0 duplicity python-protobuf libhtml-tree-perl libdatrie1
  libencode-locale-perl libportaudio2 vbetool libhttp-date-perl python-pam libmailtools-perl libcairomm-1.0-1 libjs-underscore apg python-scgi libnetfilter-conntrack3 command-not-found-data
  python-brlapi uno-libs3 libnl-genl-3-200 libnm-gtk-common libhttp-cookies-perl libsonic0 libhttp-message-perl liblouis2 iputils-arping libnfnetlink0 x11-xfs-utils libgtksourceview-3.0-common
  python-docutils espeak-data python-problem-report libnl-route-3-200 libfile-basedir-perl python-paste libssl-doc libwpd-0.9-9 apport-symptoms libnet-http-perl sphinx-common libthai0
  libminiupnpc8 remmina-common ibus-pinyin-db-android im-switch python-twisted-core xdg-utils liberror-perl xinit python-simplejson libespeak1 libhtml-format-perl libfs6 ure docutils-doc
  libdecoration0 python-twisted-names libexiv2-11 libmtp-common python-lazr.uri libsocket6-perl python-gdbm zenity-common python-formencode ubuntu-wallpapers libwnck-common libyajl1 libsysfs2
  xfonts-mathml libgpgme11 python-markupsafe evolution-data-server-common protobuf-compiler libhtml-tagset-perl libboost-serialization1.46.1 radeontool libevent-2.0-5 libzephyr4 libmhash2
  libwacom-common nux-tools python-dirspec libwpg-0.2-2 libfreerdp1 python-xkit python-roman python-jinja2 libssh-4 python-egenix-mxdatetime libglewmx1.6 python-lazr.restfulclient python-lockfile
  python-wadllib libprotoc7 iptables libwww-robotrules-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl librsync1 libgoa-1.0-common python-dateutil python-crypto adium-theme-ubuntu activity-log-manager-common
  dmidecode libmng1 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 libmythes-1.2-0 libjs-sphinxdoc libio-socket-inet6-perl python-openid libelfg0 python3.2 python3.2-minimal
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libelfg0 libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa python3.2 python3.2-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python3.2-doc binfmt-support
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  accountsservice acpi-support acpid activity-log-manager-control-center adduser aisleriot alsa-base alsa-utils anacron apparmor appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt apport apport-gtk
  apt-transport-https apt-xapian-index aptdaemon apturl apturl-common at at-spi2-core avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon avahi-utils bamfdaemon baobab bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer brasero
  brasero-cdrkit brasero-common brltty build-essential checkbox checkbox-qt colord command-not-found compiz-core compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf
  console-setup consolekit cron cryptsetup-bin cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-filters cups-ppdc dbus dbus-x11 dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service deja-dup desktop-file-utils dmsetup doc-base
  e2fsprogs eject empathy enchant evince evince-common evolution-data-server file-roller firefox firefox-gnome-support friendly-recovery ftp fuse g++ g++-4.6 gcalctool gconf-service
  gconf-service-backend gconf2 gedit gedit-common geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gettext ghostscript ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x ginn gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0
  gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-indicate-0.7 gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7
  gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 git gksu
  glib-networking glib-networking-services gnome-bluetooth gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-games-data gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-media gnome-nettool
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnomine grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gs-cjk-resource
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-x gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico gucharmap gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse
  gvfs-libs gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter hostname hplip humanity-icon-theme ibus ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-table
  ifupdown indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound indicator-status-provider-mc5 initramfs-tools
  initscripts intltool irqbalance jockey-common jockey-gtk kbd kerneloops-daemon keyboard-configuration landscape-client-ui-install language-selector-common language-selector-gnome
  libaccountsservice0 libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libatk-adaptor libatk-adaptor-schemas libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatkmm-1.6-1 libatspi2.0-0 libaudio2 libavahi-glib1
  libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libbamf0 libbamf3-0 libblkid1 libbrasero-media3-1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcairo-gobject2 libcamel-1.2-29 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0
  libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcmis-0.2-0 libcolord1 libcompizconfig0 libcroco3 libcryptsetup4 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2
  libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl3-nss libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libdconf0
  libdee-1.0-4 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libebackend-1.2-1 libebook-1.2-12 libecal-1.2-10 libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserver-1.2-15
  libedataserverui-3.0-1 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-trusty libegl1-mesa-lts-trusty libenchant1c2a libevince3-3 libexpat1-dev libfarstream-0.1-0 libfile-mimeinfo-perl libfolks-eds25
  libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgbm1-lts-trusty libgck-1-0 libgconf-2-4 libgconf2-4 libgcr-3-1 libgdata13 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdu-gtk0 libgdu0 libgee2 libgeoclue0 libgettextpo0 libgexiv2-1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty libglamor-ltst0 libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty
  libglib-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-bluetooth8 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnome-keyring0
  libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-menu2 libgnome2-common libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd7 libgnutls26 libgoa-1.0-0 libgphoto2-2 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrip0 libgs9
  libgssdp-1.0-3 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2-perl libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0
  libgtkspell-3-0 libgtop2-7 libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgudev-1.0-0 libgupnp-1.0-4 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libharfbuzz0b libibus-1.0-0
  libido3-0.1-0 libimobiledevice2 libindicate-gtk3 libindicate5 libindicator-messages-status-provider1 libindicator3-7 libindicator7 libio-socket-ssl-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1 libldap-2.4-2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmeanwhile1 libmetacity-private0 libmission-control-plugins0
  libmount1 libmusicbrainz3-6 libnautilus-extension1a libneon27-gnutls libnice10 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnss-mdns libnux-2.0-0 liboauth0
  libopenvg1-mesa-lts-trusty liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0 libp11-kit0 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpango-perl libpango1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpangomm-1.4-1 libparted0debian1 libpcre3-dev libpeas-1.0-0 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpoppler-glib8 libpopt-dev libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libpython3.4-dev libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml
  libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtbamf1 libqtcore4 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libqtgui4 libquvi7 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
  libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango
  libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core5 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librtmp0 libsane libsane-hpaio libsm6 libsmbclient libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspectre1 libspeechd2
  libssl-dev libstdc++6-4.6-dev libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtelepathy-farstream2 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger2 libtimezonemap1 libtool libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libudev1 libunique-3.0-0
  libunity-2d-private0 libunity-core-5.0-5 libunity-misc4 libunity9 libupower-glib1 libutempter0 libuuid-perl libuuid1 libvncserver0 libvte-2.90-9 libvte9 libwacom2
  libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-trusty libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck22 libwww-perl libxapian22 libxatracker2-lts-trusty libxaw7 libxkbcommon0 libxklavier16 libxml-parser-perl
  libxmu6 libxt6 libyelp0 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 light-themes lightdm linux-generic-lts-trusty linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
  linux-sound-base logrotate mahjongg media-player-info metacity metacity-common mlocate modemmanager module-init-tools mount mountall mousetweaks nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-sendto
  nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share netbase netcat-openbsd network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd ntfs-3g ntpdate nvidia-common
  obex-data-server obexd-client onboard oneconf openssh-client overlay-scrollbar parted passwd pkg-config plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text pm-utils
  policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome powermgmt-base ppp pppconfig pppoeconf pptp-linux printer-driver-c2esp printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-pnm2ppa printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-sag-gdi printer-driver-splix procps pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils python-appindicator python-apport python-apt python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-cups python-cupshelpers python-dbus python-dev python-distutils-extra
  python-gconf python-gi python-gi-cairo python-gnomekeyring python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-ibus python-notify python-packagekit python-pyatspi2 python-pycurl
  python-smbc python-software-properties python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-uno python-virtkey python-xapian python-zeitgeist python2.7-dev
  python3.4-dev qdbus qt-at-spi remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc resolvconf rfkill rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone rsyslog rtkit samba-common-bin sane-utils seahorse session-migration sessioninstaller shared-mime-info shotwell simple-scan
  smbclient sni-qt software-center software-center-aptdaemon-plugins software-properties-common software-properties-gtk speech-dispatcher ssh-askpass-gnome ssl-cert synaptic syslinux
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle telepathy-indicator telepathy-logger
  telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-salut telnet thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins transmission-gtk ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-docs
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-mono ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-couch ubuntuone-installer udev udisks
  ufw unattended-upgrades unity-2d unity-2d-common unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-common unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
  unity-lens-music unity-lens-video unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote unity-services update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common upower upstart
  ureadahead usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data usbmuxd util-linux uuid-dev uuid-runtime vino whoopsie wpasupplicant x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-utils
  x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdiagnose xorg xserver-common xserver-common-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty
  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-trusty
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-trusty
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-trusty
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-trusty
  xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-trusty
  xserver-xorg-video-sis-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-trusty
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-trusty xterm xul-ext-ubufox yelp zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity zlib1g-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libelfg0 libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa python3.2 python3.2-minimal
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  e2fsprogs libblkid1 (due to e2fsprogs) libuuid1 (due to e2fsprogs) util-linux (due to e2fsprogs) hostname mount libmount1 (due to mount)
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 745 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
69 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,471 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,718 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

I am completely overwhelmed by this output. It is not possible to install all those packages manually. In fact, I cannot install a single package, it always give me unmet dependency warning and the command `apt-get install` cannot complete. I think it might because the package management system try to install all new packages(14.04), just like a upgrade my OS, however, the process is crashed. How can revert back to a pure 12.04 in this case.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to reinstall.

Comment: Which PPA did you add? You can try to purge it, hoping it will downgrade the thing correctly. But backup first. And be prepared to reinstall; you should never mix packages from different releases... as you know now. http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) and [Why does apt output "WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed." and prompt me to enter the full phrase when purging a package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/436171/)