# Ubuntu 22.04 crashed after forcing an installation through apt

Tags: grub2, crash

Today I needed to watch some videos in .mp4 format on my laptop, so I decided to install mpv (I use Ubuntu 22.04). I did it by apt which at the moment required from me typing a command "Yes, do as i say!" to proceed. Due to the exhaust and my foolishness, I told it to proceed  and my system crashed. Let me describe every detail I remember.

Right after installation of Mpv (before rebooting) I noticed that some things changed (the wi-fi icon disappeared etc.). Then I decided to reboot my system, and instead of opening gui, black screen appeared (tty1).

When I want to open grub menu, it shows up as a minimal bash like line. Moreover, while I am in a terminal then any apt command doesn't work, so that I cannot install and reinstall
anything using apt.

For example, typing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I receive an answer

```
Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com
```

So next, I tried

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

but then it answers

```
tee: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

and I am stuck here.

I've tried many things to fix things up. I have read almost every questions and answers concerning similar crashes, but any of them helped.

I am desperately looking forward to any help, any suggestions how to fight this problem. I really would like to to avoid reinstalling my system, since I have got some important files in my home directory.

I use laptop acer Aspire 5.

Edit: I managed to access grub standard menu using USB linux.

Comment: @Nmath yes "Yes, do as I say!" is a a real thing - a kind of last ditch confirmation before a dangerous action. See for example [Why does apt output "WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed." and prompt me to enter the full phrase when purging a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436171/why-does-apt-output-warning-the-following-essential-packages-will-be-removed)

Comment: Your /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/apt/term.log contain the details we need to answer this question. Without that detail, the question is unanswerable. You have learned a valuable lesson: NEVER enter that phrase. It means you are on the wrong track and about to destroy your system. The system even clearly so warned you...but you did it anyway. Advice: Use a LiveUSB to preserve your data to some other media. Then reinstall Ubuntu. This particular egg could be un-cracked, but doing so is not worthwhile excepts as a tedious learning exercise.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I decided to reinstall Ubuntu using usb Linux. Could you please tell me how can I preserve my data exactly? I am able to boot Ubuntu only as a "live session user" and I have no (explicit!) access to my files.

Comment: I edited my question to provide you some additional and more concrete information. I still hope that somebody will be able to help me come up with a solution

Comment: Ok, I 'm sorry, I was wrong. I have an access to all my files from live session and I am able to backup them. There are still many questions but at least I managed to boot ubuntu as a live session user and access my data. Thank you for your engage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/q/91543/)